# C programming, scanf() function

Tags: c, gcc, scanf, stdin, ansi-c

Does scanf put spaces in its buffer or input stream?
If i say

```
scanf("%c %d %d", &character, &num1, &num2);
```

And now say

```
scanf("%c", &char2);
```

I know that enter will stay in the buffer but do the spaces count?

```
scanf("%c%d%d", &character, &num1, &num2);
```

Is this any different than the first part.

Also another thing.
Can I somehow break scanf after user presses enter. If it presses enter after the num1 for ex. Input: i 5

Can i somehow make scanf stop after this even though it is waiting for one more input?

Comment: Read entire lines, then parse them for example with `sscanf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A space in the format string of `scanf` will consume any white space (if any); Format specifier `%d` will also ignore any whitespaces before the actual number. So `" %d"` has the same effect as `"%d"`. Format specifier `%c` will not ignore white spaces but read them in, so `" %c"` would be different than `"%c"`. In your case, where `%c` is at the beginning of the format string of `scanf("%c %d %d", ...)` has the same effect as `scanf("%c%d%d", ...)`.

If you want to allow to exit before everything is entered, I'd suggest to read in a complete "line" using `fgets` and then parse the input accordingly, e.g. using `sscanf` of `strtok`.

Comment: Could you explain me a bit more in detail how would this scanf exiting after the enter work?